# Poca duración baterias NiCd en lollin32

Tags: arduino, esp8266

estoy desarrollando un dispositivo con un lollin32 (parecido al ESP32 pero con un conector para baterías tipo jst PH 2.0) y un DHT22. El dispositivo va en cámaras frigoríficas que funcionan entre 2 y 7 grados de temperatura. Esta estanco a humedades y el funcionamiento es recoger una temperatura cada 2 horas mandarla a la base de datos y entrar en modo deep-sleep hasta que vuelvan a pasar 2 horas.
Uso unas baterias de NiCd de 900 mAh y 3.7V (https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B00XZQJQBU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). El dispositivo tarda en mandar la temperatura 20 segundos aproximadamente cada dos horas y el resto del tiempo esta en modo deep-sleep. El problema esta en que las baterias me duran 2 o tres dias en funcionamiento cuando se supone que deberian durar bastante mas. No se cual puede ser el problema, a nivel de software creo que el codigo esta bien optimizado por lo que creo que el problema viene a nivel de hardware.

Comment: Aca arreglamos problemas de programacion... asi que si no tenes un problema de programacion, no creo que estes en el sitio indicado...

Comment: Revisa el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: Revisa las temperaturas de trabajo óptimas: `mínima` y máxima, que indique el fabricante; de todos modos, ese modelo que mencionas no es de `NiCd`, sino `NiMh`.